# disabling CSMA/CA protocol in esp8266 or any other wifi ic

Tags: wireless, wifi, esp8266, 802.11

Is there any way to disable or bypass CSMA/CA in esp8266? I don't want my packets to wait for channel to be clear. I want them to be transmitted at predefined time. If it is not possible to completely disable it, can we change random back-off period (so that we can transmit packets sooner rather than waiting for long time)? If not in esp8266 is there such functionality (of disabling CSMA/CA) in any other IC implementing WiFi protocol in 2.4 GHz band?

Edit: 
http://www.osbridge.com/download/OSBRiDGE_5G.pdf allows disabling CSMA/CA but it works in 5 GHz band. MikroTik also allows disabling CSMA/CA https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/Wireless.

Comment: Is it mentioned in the datasheet?

Comment: no, its not mentioned.

Comment: Why do you want that?  If the channel is not clear it won't be received.

Comment: we are more concerned about transmitting packets at regular intervals than receiving them correctly. Even if some packets get dropped, it does not matter much in our application.

Comment: Once you do that, it's no longer WiFi. Note that if you transmit without waiting you will not only lose your packet but jam someone else's!

Comment: You're basically asking for a feature that is **not allowed** in the WiFi protocol. So no wonder that it is not possible as allowing this would make the IC non WiFi compliant. This also means that there are no other WiFi ICs with this feature. Conclusion: you should not be using WiFi for this or not be using it this way.

Comment: i have added examples of in question. So some ICs are definitely providing this functionality. But i am more concerned about esp8266.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to disable it using rom_chip_v5_disable_cca() function defined at address 0x400060d0 in the boot ROM of esp8266 (/tools/sdk/ld/eagle.rom.addr.v6.ld file in esp8266 Arduino core gives idea about it ).

Although option to disable CCA is provided by some 802.11 chipsets and some operating systems, I would recommend not to disable it. It's one of the most important feature of WiFi protocol and disabling it just increases the number of packet drops as experiments suggest. The other functionalities of the wifi also become unpredictable.